# How to develop an Android app like a static website?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-layout, android-sdk-tools

The company I work for asks me to convert their website to an Android app. I am not an expert neither in Java, nor Android SDK. So I do not know what are my options here.

The application looks like this:

[image]

So the header (except for the title) and the footer are always constant.
And the red parts change to the relevant page when a footer button is clicked.

I know that I should not ask "*what is the best approach for this*" kind of question. So, how should I do this?

**Right now what I'm doing is this:**

two static layouts (without activity classes) : header.xml and footer.xml. I `<include>` them in the activity layouts (like *about_us.xml*). footer.xml has buttons, which are hooked to `onClick` events. Buttons are like *home , about us , references , contact*. And the onClick events are like **"load_Page_AboutUs"**

So there are 4 functions for each page (activity) to load. This is also a problem I guess. If there is a way to do it like : `load_page(String activity_name)` I would like it.

But the real problem is :

I have to define all the `load_page_x` functions in all the activities.

So if I have 4 activities, I define the below functions in 4 different activities :

```
public void load_page_about(View view)
{
 Intent i = bla();
 startActivity(i);
}
public void load_page_references(View view)
{
 Intent i = bla();
 startActivity(i);
}
// etc..
```

These set of function definitions exist in all 4 activities. So I think that I'm doing something wrong here. I would appreciate any help to guide me into the right direction. In the end:

**What I want is:**

- A single layout (xml) for the footer
- A single activity class that can handle the footer buttons' `onClick`'s
- Similarly for the header. And change its title programmatically (or from xml, if possible)

Maybe I should design page content parts as .xml files and programmattically include them in the `main_layout.xml` is it correct? And how can I do it?

Thanks for any help !

Comment: You could use a common base class for your activities. Put the common functions in there.

Comment: @Henry thanks! I tried putting the functions in MainActivity, but I cannot call MainActivity functions, unless there are static. And I cannot use startActivity in static methods. Any workaround for this ? Oh, wait. Are you saying that I should not extend Activity, but extend MyExtendedActivity? This is genius ! If it works :)

Comment: +1 henry, Elaborating Henry's comment. Create a Super class Extending Activity and Put all your common methods there now all your 4 activities must extend to this super class. Its all Inheritance.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. I appreciate it. So I guess it only remains to change the title of header programmatically, any advice for that ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14133727/2724626
visit this. it will surely help you out.

Comment: Write all your Titles of Activities in strings.xml and set the title in onCreate() of each activity.

Answer (score 1):

Fastest way would be using a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) set its java script enabled and load your index web page to it, and you're done! you might need to modify some css to view it nicely on mobile.

Comment: Thanks Warlock ! But this is not an option for now, because, even if the content is static, there are javascript functions, like animations, which cannot work in a webview, as fast as in a native app, right? And moreover, I want to learn native Android programming. I could as well make a responsive design for the website itself.